# Alternatives for when you just can't find your bones?

Tags: substitute-tool, clothing

Bones, also called *collar stays*, are those tiny little things that go in the collars of men's dress shirts. They are super easy to lose.

What quick and dirty alternatives are there for when you are in a rush and just can't find what you are looking for?

Comment: Gift cards, plastic cups, anything made of thin plastic. Use sandpaper to smooth edges after cutting, you don't want to hurt yourself or cut your shirt.

Comment: @Sempie If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Preferred method : Paperclip

Secondary Method as backup (old plastic gift card or expired credit card cut up in shapes of 'bones'

Answer (score 1):

regular, wooden coffee stirrers are my favourite.  Easy to snap to the right length, so no cutting and they come free with your morning Java!
If you find a cafe that provides the 'premium' thick wooden stirrers, then it's worth sanding off the edges and keeping a reusable set.

I just can't find the plain, stamped out brass ones I used to be able to get for a pound!

Answer (score 0):

I've never owned a shirt that requires an additional item added to the collar, but just feeling my own collar, I can tell that it has little pointy plastic things sewn into the collar. If you have an old shirt you no longer want, perhaps you could cut these things out of the collar and use them.